# How to override an included JavaScript file with GreaseMonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Example:

One page has a script: `build/function.js` and I want to replace it with `build/function2.js`.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be answered without knowing the contents of function.js .

Basically you may simply inject a new script into the document via `appendChild`,

But removing of a script will not work.

Although a script-Node may be removed, this wouldn't give the desired result. Once a (the 1st)script has been loaded, it will be parsed (and executed depending on the contents). Variables, functions etc. that already have been declared will remain until you overwrite them(this may be done via the 2nd script)